# Select items with one class and not other class jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, select

I want to select all items which are in one class and NOT in a set of other classes.  For the first step, I imagined something like this would work, but didn't:

```
$('.class1,!.class2')
```

What I actually have is a list of classes that I don't want to select:

```
dont_select = ['class2', 'class3', 'class4']
```

And I want to select all items which have class1 but not any class in my array of classes in dont_select (which varies in length).  Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".class1").not("." + dont_select.join(",.") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
$(".class1:not(.class2)")

$(".class1:not(" + dont_select.join() + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.not` function. See below,

```
dont_select = ['.class2', '.class3', '.class4']
$(selector).not(dont_select.join())
```

**Note:** Added a . to the string in dont_select array

Answer (score 0):

Your simple selector will be as below with Jquery

```
$('div.class1').not('.class2,.class3');
```

in the .not function of jquery you can put as much element as you want after ","

or if you have array then you can also go with the suggestion of Vega

```
dont_select = ['.class2', '.class3', '.class4']
$(selector).not(dont_select.join())
```

Go Ahead !!!